# Jquery Isotope shifting a tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry, jquery-isotope

I am using Isotope with filters with the following elements as my `.items`.

```
<div class="item filtername>

    <a class="fancybox" href="#fancybox">

    <div class="projimage">
      <h2>TITLE</h2>
      <img class="lazy" src="image.jpg" />
    </div><!--PROJIMAGE-->

    </a> 

    </div>
```

Isotope works, but the weird thing is that `a` tags seem to move on every other `.item`.

Some end up with the `</a>` in a different position then above, eg:

```
<div class="item filtername>

    <a class="fancybox" href="#fancybox">

    <div class="projimage">
      <h2>TITLE</h2>

     </a><!---WTF???--->

      <img class="lazy" src="image.jpg" />
    </div><!--PROJIMAGE-->

    </div>
```

I am using Lazy Load and Fancy Box in conjunction with this but I cannot figure out why this is occurring.

Would anyone know why this could be occurring?

The page is here: http://www.pixelframe.com.au/test-page.html if anyone wants to take a look.

[image]

Comment: Is the corrupted markup coming from your server? That doesn't really seem like a jQuery problem...

Comment: @meagar Im not really sure. Is there a way to check? I run 40 or so sites from the same server and never encountered this issue before

Comment: @meagar OK this is weirder - it appears fine when I view the page source, but it appears incorrect when I use Chromes element inspector...

Comment: That's impossible. Chrome's inspector is showing you the live DOM, which doesn't *have* closing tags. It's just a tree of nodes. It's impossible for them to "overlap" in the way you describe above. jQuery can't move closing tags around to an invalid state because they don't exist. I'm also not seeing what you're describing at the link you've posted.

Comment: @meagar if you hover over the thumbnails does the pointer cursor appear for each? I'll include a screen shot of what I see above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it was my CMS (ModX Revo). For some reason it freaks if you put an a tag within an a tag.